# Is there a way to disable Windows update permanently on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I tried doing it with services.msc and I tried putting a limit on bandwidth usage because I am on Wifi, and I tried a bunch of other stuffs, but nothing works and Microsoft sneakingly always enable it back and it's driving me insane since their updates install spying malwares or break some of my softwares or even the OS itself sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

> it's driving me insane since their updates install spying malwares or
> break some of my softwares or even the OS itself sometimes.

You cannot permanently stop Windows 10 Updates - not with any Windows 10 version in the last couple of years). Can't be done and anything you try will be broken by the Update Process.

That said, I keep machines current with respect to Updates and no issues.

Windows Updates most certainly do NOT install malware. That is a myth.

So then what "softwares" (multiple I assume) are breaking?  Do you have non-compliant or legacy software installed?

I suggest fixing your software so that updates work.

Comment: The components downloaded via Windows Update that directly come from Microsoft can be considered malware free, I agree with you. However the third parts components like drivers are checked but they still can be abused as the Razer mouse driver privilege escalation vulnerability shows (I assume that the vulnerable driver is downloaded through Windows Update as it can appear out of nowhere when plugging in a mouse).